# Dynamic field for Database.Upsert

Tags: apex, database

I am trying to use a dynamic field for my Database.Upsert command as follows:

```
String extField = objVariable + fieldVariable;
Database.UpsertResult[] up = Database.upsert(toUpsert, extField);
```

This however returns the following error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void upsert(List, String)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `Database.upsert()` is

```
public static Database.UpsertResult[] upsert(sObject[] recordsToUpsert, Schema.SObjectField externalIdField, Boolean allOrNone)
```

While the Boolean parameter is optional, you must provide a value of type `Schema.SObjectField` for the second parameter.

You can obtain such values dynamically via the Describe API given string input:

```
String myFieldName = 'Account';
String myObjectName = 'Name';

Schema.SObjectField f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(myObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(myFieldName);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a literal field reference (SObjectField):

```
Sobject[] records = new Account[] { new Account(Name='Test',Industry='Technology',ExtId__c='12345')};
SObjectField field = Account.ExtId__c;
Database.upsert(records, field);
```

You can't use a normal String field, because it doesn't exist as an option.